# Modify mongoose query data depend on input array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have hundred of id in a array. While fetching record from this collection with mongoose paginate so I want to add an extra key in result if result id is is present in this array then it will add a key is_checked true else false. But I don't want to run loop on the result set. It should be done with query itself

```
    Existing query

     var pageNo = parseInt(Params.page) || 1;
        var size = parseInt(Params.size) || 10;
        var userId = parseInt(Params.user_id);

        var options = {
            populate: [],
            page: pageNo,
            limit: size
        };
return await this.listModel.paginate({ user_id: userId, deleted_at: null }, options);


Here I am fetching the record from the collection for given userId with pagination

Now I have an array which has array of ids 

var recipientId = ["5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d92", "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d96", "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d96"]

My current output is 

{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Data",
    "data": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "_id": "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d92",
                "name": "test",
                "mobile": "1234567890"
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d93",
                "name": "test one",
                "mobile": "6666"
                "__v": 0
            }  
        ],
        "total": 20,
        "limit": 10,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 2

    }
}


Excpected Output


{
    "success": true,
    "message": "Data",
    "data": {
        "docs": [
            {
                "_id": "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d92",
                "name": "test",
                "mobile": "1234567890",
                "is_checked": true
                "__v": 0
            },
            {
                "_id": "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d93",
                "name": "test one",
                "mobile": "6666",
                "is_checked": false
                "__v": 0
            }  
        ],
        "total": 20,
        "limit": 10,
        "page": 1,
        "pages": 2

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to query on records which contain an array of ids, and when a certain id is present in that array you want to add an extra field is_checked, true or false.

You can do it by aggregation, as in below example we are searching for records as per location, but we have an array of fruits and if a banana is present in that array we will add a new field has_banana

Working example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/2dNYYzJid8S

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      location: "jaipur"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "store location": "$location",
      "has_bananas": {
        $in: [
          "bananas",
          "$in_stock"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And when you paginate the query you can use [$skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/)

Comment: var recipientId = ["5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d96", "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d97", "5ebe7d8355d75d56cbfb4d98"]


I am fetching the record based on some condition now if record id is prsent in above array then I want to add a key in data docs is_checked true else it will be false

Comment: Can  edit your question and add your Complete mongo query, I will update it as per your need

Comment: Sorry, but I think you may need to do check it your code once you get the data